# How to cite multiple authors without naming all them, but et. al?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I want to cite multiple authors, but only name two of them in the document, because the others are not relevant in this context.

So how can I do this?

I basically just want to add "et al." at the end of the bibliography entry.

However, if I follow the best practices for biblatex and do this:

```
@online{exodusIssueHttpAnalysis,
    author = {Jan Friebertshäuser, {@U+039b} et~al.}, % EDIT: don't copy this, the comma is used wrong here!
    title = {Documentation does not state how to run the dns/http analysis},
    subtitle = {{Issue {$\sharp$}45}},
    titleaddon = {Exodus-Privacy},
    organization = {GitHub},
    date = {2020-08-26},
    urldate = {2020-08-26},
    language = {english},
    url = {https://github.com/Exodus-Privacy/exodus/issues/45},
}
```

It does get mixed up though and I end up with this: [image: @U+039b et al. Jan Friebertshäuser]

I know I could make it a "company name" and prevent BibLaTeX from interfering with it all, by placing them in `{}` brackets, but this is not how it should properly be done, I guess?
Especially, as I just want to add that there are more authors – all other things BibLaTeX can freely change, like the order of the authors or what it does etc.

Comment: What does "I want to ... name two of [the authors] in the document, because the others are not relevant" mean?

Comment: Well, as you can see in the example I want to list just these two, not three. "Person a, person B and others" it should basically mean. 
You do see I cite a GitHub issue, and there everyone who ever commented can be considered an author – but just one or two people do say the relevant things I refer to. That is the underlying problem.

Comment: I'm struggling with why you use a comma in the `author` field the way you do. The keyword `and` must be used in the `author` field to separate authors. Do give `author = {Jan Friebertshäuser and {@U+039b} and others}` a try. (Yes, `others` is also a keyword in the `author` field.)

Comment: Ahhh maybe `others` is the solution here. Thanks I'll try that out.

Comment: (I thought biblatex is so clever to use `,` in the same as `and` and previously it also always did hmm.)

Comment: In the `author` field, commas and `and` are definitely not substitutes.

Comment: Whatever else you do, please do replace `{$\sharp$}45` with `\#45`.

Comment: Okay, an add-on autocorrected that. It worked hehe…

Comment: @Mico Okay indeed `others` is the exact and much more intelligent solution I was searching for, but did not imagine.
Also thanks for the other tips.

Do you want to submit this as a reply/answer here, so I can resolve this question and give you the upvotes?

Comment: ok, give me a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `author` field of a bibliographic entry, the keyword `and` must be used to separate individual authors. The `author` field knows of another keyword as well: `others`, which serves to trigger the routine that outputs "et al" in the citation callouts (if it hasn't already been triggered).

Hence, I believe that you should write the field as

```
author = {Jan Friebertshäuser and {@U+039b} and others},
```

The curly braces around `@U+039b` are probably not strictly necessary. However, they might guard against the `+` character being somehow misinterpreted.